# How to disable paste in Cloud9 Ace Code Editor?

Tags: ace-editor

I am using CloudA9 Code Editor for my College Project. How can I disable the Paste in Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
stop = function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); console.log(e) 
}
document.querySelector(".ace_editor").addEventListener("paste", stop, true);
```

or

```
editor.onPaste = function() { return ""; }
```

​